# Divide Overflow on Intel x86

Tags: debugging, dosbox

I'm running assembly code in the DOs mode debugger and I'm getting a divide overflow.  The debugger doesn't tell me where the instruction was executed (I have several places that it could occur), and I also have executed many iterations through a search algorithm.  Is there any way to trap on this exception and get some useful information?

I'm using DEBUG.EXE (supplied to Windows XP).  Do you know how the interface to INT 0 works?  I assume it's system call from my .com program.

Comment: Which debugger exactly are you using?

Comment: If you're working in real mode, one option would be to hook interrupt 0, which is what the CPU raises on divide error.